Is there any way to get LF/HF ratio using CMSIS DSP Library APIs?
In a c/c++ project, I have been able to run fft, ifft, cfft on given signal using CMSIS DSP APIs. However, I need to extract LF/HF ratio from the signal. In Python there are APIs to measure it using scipy signal. Is there any implementation in C/C++? Can I use CMSIS DSP APIs to achieve this?

No such thing as C/C++, asking for recommendations is OT on stackoverflow. You should know better.
